# ir de una un fragment a otro al seleccionar un item de un ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragment

Al ejecutar y hacer **click** en el item del `listview` se cierra la app. ¿ alguna idea para solucionar esto ?

La lista esta en  un fragment, y quiero ir a otro fragment

**Les dejo mi codigo**

```
public class DiezFrut extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public DiezFrut() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment DiezFrut.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static DiezFrut newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        DiezFrut fragment = new DiezFrut();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_diez_frut, container, false);
        ListView dfrutas;
        String [] frutas;

        dfrutas = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.DiezFrutas);
        frutas=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Diezfrutas);

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,frutas);
        dfrutas.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        dfrutas.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                 switch(i)
                {
                    case 0:getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,new Uno_Cerezas()).commit();
break;
                }
            }
        });

        return view;



    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }



    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

clase Uno_Cerezas

```
public class Uno_Cerezas extends Fragment {

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public Uno_Cerezas() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_uno__cerezas, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

> 01-17 19:49:08.173 29672-29672/com.aguila0017.fruits E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                          Process: com.aguila0017.fruits, PID: 29672
>                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: com.aguila0017.fruits.MainActivity@2c0774
>   must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
>                                                                              at com.aguila0017.fruits.Uno_Cerezas.onAttach(Uno_Cerezas.java:47)
>                                                                              at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1048)
>                                                                              at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.setLastIn(BackStackRecord.java:838)
>                                                                              at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.calculateFragments(BackStackRecord.java:878)
>                                                                              at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:719)
>                                                                              at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1682)
>                                                                              at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:541)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 01-17
>   19:49:09.820 29672-29672/com.aguila0017.fruits I/Process: Sending
>   signal. PID: 29672 SIG: 9

Comment: iba a contestar, me parece tienes correcto el realizar la transacción pero si dices " se me cierra la app" es importante agregues el mensaje desplegado en el LogCat, si desarrollas en Android y no revisas el LogCat puedes estar buscando infinidad de soluciones sin corregir el problema.

Comment: ya agregue el mensaje

Comment: Muchas gracias Sergio, agrego respuesta. Agrega al interfaz que indico en tu Fragmento Uno_Cerezas.

Answer (score 1):

Tu `MainActivity`tiene que implementar `OnFragmentInteractionListener`. Asumimos que tu actividad extende activity, necesites:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnFragmentInteractionListener{

    // luego en alguna parte de MainActivity
    @Override
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri){
        //lo que quieres hacer en caso de interacción
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error indica que debes implementar `OnFragmentInteractionListener` :

> **must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener at** com.aguila0017.fruits.Uno_Cerezas.onAttach(Uno_Cerezas.java:47) at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1048)

En realidad el problema es que esta interface no esta agregada en tus clase Fragmento, en este caso debes agregarla en `Uno_Cerezas`.

```
   public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
```

---

**Actualización**:

Gracias por tu actualización, veo:

> com.aguila0017.fruits.MainActivity@2c0774 must implement
>   OnFragmentInteractionListener at
>   com.aguila0017.fruits.Uno_Cerezas.onAttach(Uno_Cerezas.java:47)

Ahora asegura que `MainActivity` implementa `OnFragmentInteractionListener`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnFragmentInteractionListener{
   ...
   ...
   ...
   }
```

Al realizar esto te pedira implementación de métodos por lo cual agregara:

```
@Override
void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri){
    ...
 }
```

Comment: pero ya la tiene

Comment: voy a publicar el codigo de esa calse

Comment: @Sergio agregue actualización. No se porque el -1 lo que sucede es que al inicio no se tenia el código en la pregunta

Comment: El -1 fue porque implicaste que Uno_Cerezas tuviera que implementar la interfaz, mientras la excepción declaró claramente que es el contexto donde hay que implementar la interfaz (conjunto con el código donde se tira la excepción). Por lo mismo te di la pista en el chat. ;) los -1 se pueden perder después de la correción. ;)

Comment: @StefanNolde te comento que al inicio el OP no tenìa nada en su pregunta incluso ni el còdigo, ahora que la vez es obvio que la primera parte de mi respuesta es lo que tiene el usuario.

Comment: Pero compartiste parte de la misma excepción en tu respuesta ;) Como hiciste eso si no estaba todavía?

Comment: Pense por la excepción que tenía implementado el listener en la Activity pero no el método. Si realizas la prueba marca el mismo error si no implementas sus metodos.